# MBaaS Push: How to send payloads larger than 256 bytes?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-cloud, mbaas

With iOS 8, the payload size limit for push notifications has been [increased to 2 kilobyes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html). In an attempt to make use of this with MBaaS Push on Bluemix, I received the following error message: "Bad Request - The notification payload exceeds the maximum size limit ( 256 bytes) allowed for iOS platform." (FPWSE1080)

Is there a way to work around this limitation? If not, are there any plans for MBaaS Push to support the increased payload size?

I need cross-platform support, so using the MobileFirst for iOS Push service is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a current limitation and there are no plans for MBaaS to support the increased payload size.

Apologies for the inconvenience.